# Why does my array only update with "" when I trigger a UIAlert

Tags: swift

I have created a UIAlert, which spawns a textbox, where the user must enter text and click ok. From there I want to amend the array I created named roomList to update with the output from the text box, and show in the tableview on the app.

Currently, upon clicking the button, the array updates with an additional "" every time, and nothing is added when the user inputs into the text box.

It almost looks like the button is triggering an empty string to be published?

Code below:

```
@IBAction func addRoomButton(_ sender: Any) {

    showAlert()
    
}
// UIAlertcontroller that is used to pop up a message where the user can enter text. This allows the user to add an item to the room list.
func showAlert()
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter New Room", message: "Add your new room below", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Room Name"
            roomList.append(textField.text!)
        }
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print(roomList)
}
```

Grateful if anyone can advise what I am missing here, and where the "" is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending new element into the `roomList` array from the `addTextField` method of `UIAlertController` which will always produce an empty `String` (""). To get the value you need you've to append new element into `roomList` in the action handler:

```
func showAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter New Room", message: "Add your new room below", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { _ in
        if let room = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
            roomList.append(room)
        }
    })
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Room Name"
    }
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print(roomList)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have solved the problem. Is there an easy way to refresh the tableview on screen with that input?